# Importing JS libraries to Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hammer.js

I'm trying to use `hammer.js` on my project, however I'm having trouble importing it. I have installed the library through `npm` by `npm i hammerjs`. Imported it on my `main.js` file as `import 'hammerjs'` and then when I do

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement, myOptions)
hammertime.on('pan', function(ev) {
console.log(ev)
})
```

I get errors saying `Hammer` is not defined. What is the correct way to import libraries in vue?

Answer (score 4):

You can include `hammerjs` with:

```
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs'
```

A side note: You can do the same to include other libraries installed with `npm` in your vue project. For example, if you want to include `ThreeJS` In your .js or .vue files, simply type in:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want, install the wrapper hammerjs to vue, follow the link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-hammer

otherwise, do you need include the lib on the index.html, but a don't recommend.

ps: I would like do comment, but i don't have reputation.

Comment: I have tried this and it works, but unfortunately it doesn't support all the gestures the original library supports, specifically `pinchin`and `pinchout`.